# Freeware e-mail client for small companies excluding Thunderbird

Tags: email, email-client

I'm looking for some e-mail client with:

- multi accounts,
- `IMAP` protocol,
- signatures,
- e-mail addresses sync,
- freeware for business use.

I don't want `Thunderbird` because it freezes sometimes and stops receiving new mails. Synchronisation is riddiculous... Annoying thing is search box... The results aren't clear at all.

I wonder if there's any that works fine, has all the options I want and is freeware.

Alternatively if there's some non-freeware that is noticeable, you can list it here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I'm certain there are many. Have you tried Google?

Comment: Yeah, I thought about Google Web client, but the problem is I can't do different signatures for myself. And we need to use one mail in our company + the 2nd individual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use OperaMail (http://www.opera.com/computer/mail), eM Client (http://www.emclient.com/) or Evolution (http://projects.gnome.org/evolution/)

I think that the best is OperaMail

Comment: We use OperaMail. It looks really fine:) Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I'd go for the e-mail client that is built in the Opera browser if I had a small company. You have one application for web browsing and e-mail communication with lots of features. I however have no idea whether you are able to choose you browser freely.

Other alternatives could be Pegasus Mail and Incredimail.